# Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1

Tags: java, android, maven

i have some problem in my program

when i put this code in build.gradle

[image: see screenshot]

i got this error

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Liverpool) from AndroidManifest.xml:8:9-34
    is also present at [com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-38:19 to override.
```

when i only put this code in `build.gradle`

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

i got this error

```
Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Bonata/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication5/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
}  are you adding the dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way using maven:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Or, using Gradle, it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: when i delete maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        } i get this error Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0   , i can't put 2 maven

Comment: It may be because you've got another errors. The IDE first compiles the BubbleView's library, gets an error then stops, when you fix this error, the IDE tries to compile the other part of your code, then gets the Twitter's library error.

Comment: so what's your solution to add 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1' without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should return this line: `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

To fix first error you should add to your AndroidManifest.xml in `application` tag this line: `tools:replace="android:label"`

Comment: this link image maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNFOdRuq932rlTtdZcnkUVGSr-r7zeQEiikkqHk   ,,  this errors https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipMOLH0S9Dmq9pP0YdXcLRgTqDrRplMl2gY-l59h  hope you understand

Comment: @LadestamBonaTa 404